# Selecting content at design time inside a dependancy property of a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a User Control that I'm using to control the content of all the pages I have in a project. It allows me to easily control the header and footers of the page and have matching styles etc etc. I designed this all in Visual Studio 2010 and used the XAML Designer built in to layout all my pages. I used to be able to click on objects on the design surface that were inside the MainContent dependency property and have it highlight the XAML definition of that control. After I upgraded to VS2012, something broke and now it will only highlight flxv:MasterPageCustomControl when I click on any of the content inside my MainContent Grid. I've tried to fix it several times and lived with it for over a year now... can anyone help me? I'm not sure how much more information to provide.

```
<flxv:MasterPageCustomControl HeaderTitle="Display Menu" 
                              HeaderDescription="Modify the properties and content of this display"
                              HeaderIcon="/SFD.Client;component/Images/32x32/plasma-tv.png"
                              FooterContentTemplate="{StaticResource FooterContentTemplate}">
    <flxv:MasterPageCustomControl.MainContent>

        <Grid>
            <Button/>
        </Grid>

    </flxv:MasterPageCustomControl.MainContent>
</flxv:MasterPageCustomControl>
```

User Control Code:

```
public partial class MasterPageCustomControl : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
{
    #region Fields

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterContentTemplateProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderDescriptionProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderIconProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTitleProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MainContentProperty;

    #endregion Fields

    #region Properties

    public DataTemplate FooterContentTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(FooterContentTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FooterContentTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public string HeaderDescription
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderDescriptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderDescriptionProperty, value); }
    }

    public string HeaderIcon
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderIconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderIconProperty, value); }
    }

    public string HeaderTitle
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTitleProperty, value); }
    }
    public object MainContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(MainContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainContentProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Constructors

    static MasterPageCustomControl()
    {
        FooterContentTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "FooterContentTemplate",
            typeof(DataTemplate),
            typeof(MasterPageCustomControl));

        HeaderDescriptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HeaderDescription",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MasterPageCustomControl));

        HeaderIconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HeaderIcon",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MasterPageCustomControl));

        HeaderTitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HeaderTitle",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MasterPageCustomControl));

        HeaderWorkstationVisiblity = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HeaderWorkstationVisiblity",
            typeof(Visibility),
            typeof(MasterPageCustomControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));

        MainContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MainContent",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(MasterPageCustomControl));

        // ---------------------------------------

        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MasterPageCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MasterPageCustomControl)));
    }
```

Comment: Am not sure, try by holding ctrl or alt key and click the control that you want to select...

Comment: Same behavior as a regular click. Thanks for the idea though.